# Pandas analysis of data in csv

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to code a statistical model using pandas. First i wanna start by doing a simple mean and median check of the price. I have shown data in csv below.

what I have tried:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('audi-a4.csv', index_col=False, header=0);
serie = df.transpose() # here we convert the DataFrame into a Se
x = serie.describe()
print(serie)
print(x)
```

Data in CSV:

```
NoteDate    Fuel    StartDate   BestContactTime PriceDisplay    IsBold  Make    Transmission    Category    Owners  HasFreeShipping Year    EngineSize  AsAt    IsDealer    Doors   ExteriorColour  Odometer    StartPrice  NumberPlate ImportHistory   EndDate Cylinders   Title   Vin CategoryPath    WofExpires  BodyStyle   ListingLength   Suburb  StereoDescription   ListingId   Region  Model   RegistrationExpires
    /Date(0)/   Petrol  /Date(1457523875033)/   Evening $17,985 TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005    2000    /Date(1457854140345)/   FALSE   0   Dark Blue   61988   17985   ABC123      /Date(1458128675033)/   0   Audi A4 Test887 2005    WAUZZZ8EX5A457186   /Trade-Me-Motors/Cars/Audi  /Date(0)/   Sedan       Whangarei       4554769 Northland   A4  /Date(0)/
    /Date(0)/   Petrol  /Date(1457525091850)/   Evening $17,985 TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005    2000    /Date(1457854140345)/   FALSE   0   Dark Blue   61988   17985   ABC123      /Date(1458129891850)/   0   Audi A4 Test biz1 2005  WAUZZZ8EX5A457186   /Trade-Me-Motors/Cars/Audi  /Date(0)/   Sedan       Whangarei       4554770 Northland   A4  /Date(0)/
    /Date(0)/   Petrol  /Date(1457530941643)/   Evening $17,985 TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005    2000    /Date(1457854140345)/   FALSE   0   Dark Blue   61988   17985   ABC123      /Date(1458135741643)/   0   Audi A4 Test123 2005    WAUZZZ8EX5A457186   /Trade-Me-Motors/Cars/Audi  /Date(0)/   Sedan       Whangarei       4554773 Northland   A4  /Date(0)/
    /Date(0)/   Petrol  /Date(1457532268097)/   Evening $17,985 TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005    2000    /Date(1457854140345)/   FALSE   0   Dark Blue   61988   17985   ABC123      /Date(1458137068097)/   0   Audi A4 Luxary Ship for Sale 2005   WAUZZZ8EX5A457186   /Trade-Me-Motors/Cars/Audi  /Date(0)/   Sedan       Whangarei       4554774 Northland   A4  /Date(0)/
    /Date(0)/   Petrol  /Date(1457612061090)/   Evening $17,985 TRUE    Audi    Automatic   0001-0268-0271- 0   TRUE    2005    2000    /Date(1457854140345)/   FALSE   0   Dark Blue   61988   17985   ABC123      /Date(1458216861090)/   0   Audi A4 Well Established, EST T/O $8.8M, Owne 2005  WAUZZZ8EX5A457186   /Trade-Me-Motors/Cars/Audi  /Date(0)/   Sedan       Whangarei       4557063 Northland   A4  /Date(0)/
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert to a series? also is this csv snippet really what the csv looks like as your code as it stands won't parse this correctly as you have space delimeters and not commas, why are there `/` in some of your data?

Answer (score -1):

First, you're going to want to get those "/" and the "," out of your data frames. For the mean of a column, you can use the df.mean() function from pandas.